# Generating a link containing a fragment with ASP.Net MVC Routelink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, fragment-identifier, routelink

I'm trying to use Html.RouteLink within a view to generate a link to a named anchor on another page. There's a few definitions for RouteLink that include a fragment option but I'm trying to figure out if there's another way.

```
public static string RouteLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string routeName,
    string protocol,
    string hostName,
    string fragment,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

is the obvious solution, but kind of clunky seeming. I'd prefer to be able to do something like

```
Html.RouteLink("Looga", new { Controller = "Cooga", Action = "Aooga", Fragment = "Fooga" })
```

and have that return

```
<a href="/Cooga/Aooga#Fooga">Looga</a>
```

Is that possible or will I need to specify every little part of the URL to get fragment using the built-in helpers. I could also just do it manually like

```
<a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "Cooga", Action = "Aooga" }) %>#Fooga>Looga</a>
```

but it seems like something RouteLink should be able to handle more elegantly.

Comment: Having to define protocol & hostname just so I can append a fragment seems silly. I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited to take account of main post edits**

<del>Html.RouteLink( 
        "Looga",

        new { Controller = "Cooga", Action = "Aooga" }, 
        new { Fragment = "Fooga" })</del>

This code will current produce

```
<a href="/Cooga/Aooga" Fragment="Fooga">Looga</a>
```

Not really what you want.  Instead, you could write your own extension method for RouteLink, something like this...

```
public static class RouteLinkExtensions
{
    public static string RouteLink( 
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        object routeValues, 
        string fragment)
    {
        // There's probably better ways to do the implementation, but you get the idea
        var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}#{1}>{2}</a>",
                                url.RouteUrl(routeValues), 
                                fragment,
                                linkText); 
    }
}
```

This will allow you to use a clean call to RouteLink in your page :-)

```
Html.RouteLink( 
    "Looga",  
    new { Controller = "Cooga", Action = "Aooga" }, 
    "Fooga")
```

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing. Sorry about the janky example, I wasn't paying enough attention. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Russell.

Here's a slightly edited version of his extension which i changed to suit my purposes ... thought I would post it in case it helps someone.

Changes I made:

- It now returns and Html string rather than a string so that you can use it for rendering the link straight into the page.
- I changed it to accept a route name rather than a routevalues object
- I also changed it so that if the fragment you pass in is empty it doesn't append the '#'

`public static class HtmlHelperRouteLinkExtension
        {
            public static IHtmlString RouteLink(
            this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            string linkText,
            string routeName,
            string fragment)
            {
                var url = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
                return htmlHelper.Raw(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}{1}\">{2}</a>",
                       url.RouteUrl(routeName),
                       String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fragment) ? "" : "#" + fragment,
                       linkText));
            }
        }`